# [Android bound service][Binder vs messenger]

Tags: android

I am trying to understand the difference between binding service using messenger and binder class.In android documentation it has been written that messenger class should be used when we need to access service through remote procedure.But I am not able to locate an example which illustrate an implementation which cannot be done using binder class.

Comment: so what problem do you have with?

Comment: I just need an example,where IPC can be implemented using messenger class,but same cannot be done using binder class

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just want to understand the difference

Answer (score -2):

As I know these two classes support IPC in Android. However Binder is more powerful than Messenger.
And there are 3 different points between Binder & Messenger:

- Messenger supports communication between two processes, Binder doesn't(I mean you use Binder only)
- Binder & AIDL allow keep communication between two processes run on two separate apps. Messenger can't do this.
- Binder & AIDL support multi-thread. In contrast, Messenger doesn't.

I wrote two simple demos for Messenger & Binder in IPC. Hope they could help you.

https://github.com/nguyentrungduy/Interprocess-with-Messenger
https://github.com/nguyentrungduy/Interprocess-With-AIDL